# Angular 5 call to Spring Restful Controller

Tags: typescript, angular5, spring-restcontroller

1. I am using Spring boot and have the following Restful Controller. Its working fine and I tested it with PostMan.

   ```
   @RestController
   public class AuthController {

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;  

   @PostMapping("/login")
   public User login(@RequestBody User user) {
       User currentUser = userRepository.findOneByUserIdAndPassword(user.getUserId(), user.getPassword());
       System.out.println("currentUser : "+currentUser);
       return (currentUser == null ? new User() : currentUser);
   }
   }
   ```
2. Angular 5 Credentials Object:

   ```
   export class Credentials {

   userId: string;
   password: string;

   constructor(userId: string, password: string) {
       this.userId = userId;
       this.password = password;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Angular 5 Component : login.component.ts

   ```
   login(): void {

      //Looking to do something like this.
      User user = this.authService.login(this.credentials);
      if(user.userId === '') {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      } else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
   }
   ```
4. Angular 5 Service : auth.service.ts

Trying with this function.

```
login(credentials : Credentials): Promise<User> {
return this.http
  .post(API_URL + '/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), httpOptions)
  .toPromise()
  .then(() => User)
  .catch(this.handleError);

  }
```

But I am getting this error on call. The call is not reaching the server as well.

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"body":{"error":"Collection 'undefined' not found"},"url":"http://localhost:8080/login","headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found"}
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
```

I also tried to use but couldn't get the call working.

```
login(credentials : Credentials): Observable<Credentials> {
    return this.http.post<Credentials>(API_URL + '/login', credentials, httpOptions);
}
```

Appreciate on any pointers.

Comment: Are the spring API and the client app at some domain? If not, it maybe caused by cors. does your API app has cors enabled?

Comment: I added the following in proxy.conf.json (same folder where package.json is defined). {
    "/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

Comment: I think you should give more details about the http request error (client request url, response status code, body and etc), not just the code and the config file, which should be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your latest attempt looks much correcter but you need to subscribe to your login function, if you do not do so, the call will never be fired. Within the subscribe function your credentials delivered by the service will be available. See https://angular.io/guide/http for more details.

```js
this.authService.login(this.credentials).subscribe((user) => {
   if(user.userId === '') {
     this.isLoggedIn = false;
   } else {
     // probably a copy+paste issue to set it to false?
     this.isLoggedIn = false;
   }
}
```